# Is it correct to do pre-filtering before multiple tests?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I often see that authors of large-scale studies that theoretically have to perform multiple test correction for enormous amount of tests do pre-filtering, in other words - throw away all tests that does not look good from "the first sight" (eg, comparison of 10000 features between two groups - researchers may throw away all features with big variances or [small variances](https://clinicalepigeneticsjournal.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s13148-017-0320-z) before doing any tests).

Eg, one good and surely correct example of pre-filtering: Tarone's trick, eg on 7th slide here: https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/bsse/borgwardt-lab/documents/talk_slides/KBorgwardt_UniBasel_20160421.pdf .

But the correctness of pre-filtering is sometimes not so obvious in other studies. Sometimes it literally looks like "we filter p-values that are greater than 0.5" or close to it, "majority of examples we filter out most probably have large p-values" - but in other words, they may use "effect size" instead of "p-value" (while applying t-test), and so on.

**The question is:** when pre-filtering of some tests before FDR control procedure is correct, and when it is cheating?

UPD: I found [this](http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/107/21/9546.full.pdf) paper that obviously address the issue, but only started to read it.

Comment: Surely that's just a way of cheating. If the goal is to generate significant p-values, why both with controlling for multiple testing, or doing work, at all? Just make up p < 0.05. Or p < 0.005 for that matter.

Comment: @AdamO thanks! I was doubting it - it is really widely used in life sciences. Now I will be sure =)

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood the recommendation of Tarone's method. [Read his paper yourself](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2531456). Tarone pointed out that the $p$-value for discrete analyses has a theoretical lower bound. For instance, if one measures the following $2 \times 2$ contingency table relating an allele pattern to a disease status:

$$ \begin{array}{rcc} 
 & \text{Cancer} & \text{Disease free} \\ \hline
\text{aa} & 4 & 0 \\
\text{aA or AA} & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}$$

The table demonstrates the *largest possible* association that this design can achieve: an odds ratio of $\infty$ but a two-sided p-value of 0.02857 = 2/70 where 70 is the number of permutations of tables 8 patients having 4 diseased and 4 disease free and 4 homozygous recessive genotypes and 4 heterozygous or homozygous dominant genotypes. $p = 0.02857$ is the smallest achievable $p$-value in this case. If two or more comparisons are made, the significance level of 0.025 is *theoretically impossible to achieve*.

Tarone's method immediately discards such tests **not** on the basis of being *statistically non-significant* but on the basis of *lacking precision*. This decision was based only on the actual marginal frequencies (4/4 by 4/4). This was sufficient to discredit the comparison.

Comment: No-no, I understood it, that's why I wrote that it is obviously correct, I was wandering about other methods, such as "if the variance is big - we do not test this feature", or "we have small number of points (eg when a lot of data is missing) - we do not test it" without justification such as in Tarone's or Gilbert's paper. There are a lot of such tricks, like "if we do not test data that does not look promising - we reduce number of comparisons", however it is cheating, as you explained in your comment.

Comment: I honestly have seen a lot of such "pre-filtering" that was not justified, but when I tried to google for example I found only correct examples. But eg this paper provides an idea of the phenomena I'm talking about: https://clinicalepigeneticsjournal.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s13148-017-0320-z (I am not saying it is obviously wrong or not useful)

Comment: In the paper above authors write honestly "empirically driven" and they use similar ideas to the ones you described (to remove tests with low variability so the effect of reasonable size can not be detected). So probably it is not 100% correct, but it is useful. Where is the border between "cheating" and "correct filtering"? It is clear that filtering can not be p-value based, but eg effect size based using t-test is basically the same... - you partially answer it in your last paragraph, could you elaborate more on the general situation?

Comment: @GermanDemidov thanks for sharing the paper. I'll take a closer look and let you know what I think. Sorry I misunderstood your affirmation of Tarone's method. I see some similarity in excluding comparisons on the basis of too-high variance or too-small sample size (the exclusion is not done based on the actual result).

Comment: @GermanDemidov I think what the authors propose here is valid for the same reason Tarone's method is valid. When they say "no variance", they mean that methylation is constant for all those values. You know that *any* T-test would be non-significant regardless of what the actual grouping variable is. It is a legitimate reason to discard such tests beforehand and improve power elsewhere.

Comment: what do you think about general review, provided in the UPD in the main post? I am not sure that it covers all the situations and not sure that I fully understand the whole picture...